# Multiple conditions in one statement

Tags: php, validation, conditional-statements

I'm adding some very basic validation to a "name" form field. Generally, it's impossible to actually validate a name, but I figured I could at least verify that it's not empty, greater than maybe 2 characters (Al is the shortest name I can think of), and that those characters aren't just empty space.

Here's the conditionals I'm using:

```
// Check length of name field
if(!isset($name) || $name < 2 || (strlen($name) > 0 && strlen(trim($name)) == 0)) {
    // Name field only spaces
    if((strlen($name) > 0 && strlen(trim($name)) == 0) || trim($name) == '') {
        $errors['name'] = "Please enter a real name...";
    }
    // Name too short
    else {
        $errors['name'] = "Are you sure <strong>".htmlspecialchars($name)."</strong> is your name?";
    }
    $msg_type = "error";
}
```

However, when I run this with a valid name, I get the "Name too short" error. I know it's got to be a problem with how I'm combining the conditionals, but I can't figure out where that problem lies.

Comment: it's good habit to **always** use `()` around each condition

Comment: $name < 2 is checking if it's value is less than 2 not the character number

Comment: You use the same check (`(strlen($name) > 0 && strlen(trim($name)) == 0)`) twice. Why?

Comment: There actually are some people with one-letter names out there.

Comment: @kojiro i m guessing his target audience isn't asian >.<

Comment: Ah, yes... I forgot to wrap `$name` with `strlen()`. Thanks!

Comment: Aww and I was all set to register to your site with username "3"

Comment: @PatsyIssa Harry S. Truman wasn't Asian and his middle name is just 'S'.

Comment: I highly doubt he would have registered with a website as just "S", however.

Comment: More's the point, though, what purpose does it serve to prevent users from entering a single-letter name? Who will that make happy?

Comment: Me. It's a contact form on my website. If someone is going to reach out to me and expect a reply, the least they can do is give me a real name to reply to. I honestly don't see that as being too irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$name < 2` doesn't work. You're trying to use `strlen($name) < 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a tool called **regex** which people have invented for string matching and it could be pretty conveniently used for validation cases like yours. If you want to validate a word let's say with at least 2 characters of length, you could do the following:

```
if(!preg_match('/\b\w{2,}/', $name)) {
    $errors['name'] = "Are you sure <strong>".htmlspecialchars($name)."</strong> is your name?";
}
```

Where:
\b: word boundary
\w: word character
{2,}: two or more times for the word character